# Woocomerce use GeoIP2 instead of GeoLite2

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation

I am trying to use the paid version of [MaxMind GeoLocation database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip?lang=en) in Woocommerce but can't find a way to integrate it and automatically update the database like the free version?

I see in the class `WC_Integration_MaxMind_Database_Service` there is a filter to update the path to the file but the file name `GeoLite2-Country` seems fixed in a `const`

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-integrations-maxmind-geolocation-class-wc-integration-maxmind-database-service.html

```
function plugin_woocommerce_new_maxmind_geolocation_database_path($database_path) {
     $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();     
     $database_path = trailingslashit($upload_dir['basedir']) . 'GeoIP2-City.mmdb';     
     return $database_path; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_maxmind_geolocation_database_path', 'plugin_woocommerce_new_maxmind_geolocation_database_path' )
```

Comment: Can you show your code using `woocommerce_maxmind_geolocation_database_path`

Comment: @HowardE 
`function plugin_woocommerce_new_maxmind_geolocation_database_path($database_path)
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $database_path = trailingslashit($upload_dir['basedir']) . 'GeoIP2-City.mmdb';
    return $database_path;
}`


`add_filter( 'woocommerce_maxmind_geolocation_database_path', 'plugin_woocommerce_new_maxmind_geolocation_database_path' );`

Comment: Are you sure the database file is where you say it is?